# X server doesn't "wake up" upon resume from suspend

Tags: xorg, suspend, power-management, 19.04, thinkpad

I run 19.04 on a [Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (6th gen)](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-6th-gen-type-20kh-20kg) [HW manual](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/x1_carbon_6thgen_hmm_en.pdf). I've been using Ubuntu on it since I bought it in December 2018, and since then suspend/resume has worked without incident.

There used to be some problems with this laptop, but Lenovo provided a BIOS update to allow it to go into [S3 sleep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/system-sleeping-states) (whatever that means) and that's how I've always had my BIOS configured. I've used it a lot, suspending and resuming several times a day (not every day, but quite often) for months.

At some point about a month or so ago an 18.04 software update made it stop working. I upgraded to 19.04 and that didn't help. Now I can suspend the system just fine, and it goes into the "throbbing light" suspension state correctly. However when I wake the system up, the X server does not wake up.

I can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and get to a plain text console, and I see there the system has in fact correctly resumed from sleep. I can do a `ps` and see that `Xorg` is still running (often, inexplicably, on both tty7 and tty8). I have found no way to get it to wake up and prompt for a password to unlock the slept session, and I end up either killing the `Xorg` process(es) or rebooting.

What can I do to debug or investigate what's going on?

Comment: Added a few web links; you may find the HW manual esp. useful someday.

Comment: Ugh, I still have this with 22.04  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update to 20.04.1***

Internet searches return a variety of suggestions, none of which have worked for me. Had posted an updated workaround, only to have it suddenly fail. So count me among those looking for a workable solution -- until this is fixed.

**-- Original Answer --**

This is a kernel bug that affects a wide array of hardware. A quick search found the updated kernel (that fixes the breaking on resume-from-suspend) is not available for 19.04 yet (to potentially save you the trouble reverting to 18.04).

So the current fix would be to re-install 18.04, then check the kernel version:

```
uname -r
```

If it returns "4.15...," then upgrade manually to the hardware enablement stack ("hwe," which would eventually be auto-installed anyway) with:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

All your troubles will melt away after this (at least, mine did).

```
uname -r
5.3.0-42-generic
```

(See history for earlier updates)

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure you correctly identified my issue. Now I'm on 19.10 and I don't have this particular problem any more, though now I've got issues with suspend taking a really long time or not working at all. Sigh.

Comment: "Sigh" is right. Took many hours of searching to find the answers, only to realize they raised more questions! Bleh. Whenever a search/find happens, I try to make at least one post to help the next person. Thanks for the clear phrasing of your question, which gave this top pagerank. ... If no reversion to 18.04, then likely have to wait for 20.04.1 this summer to upgrade w/ kernel fix.